# The expectation of total number of different states in N time points

Tags: probability, combinatorics, markov-chains

[Conditions]

(1) An object has K possible states.

(2) This object can have only one state at a single time point.

(3) The probability of each state at any single time point is 1/K, and each time point is independent of another.

[Question] What is the expectation of different states appearing in N time points? (Obviously, this expectation should be less than K. )

Someone told me the solution is $K(1-(1-\frac{1}{K})^N)$, but I could not understand his explanation.

So here I hope you to validate this solution, and provide detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give the answer you quote, you need a stronger version of (3) so that the states at each time point are independent of each other.

Hints:

- What is the probability that at any particular time point the object has a partiuclar state $x$?
- What is the probability that at any particular time point the object does not have state $x$?
- What is the probability that at all $N$ time points the object does not have state $x$?
- What is the probability that at at least one of $N$ time points that the object has state $x$?
- What is the expectation of an indicator that at at least one of $N$ time points the object has state $x$?
- What is the sum over all $K$ states of the expectations of an indicator that at at least one of $N$ time points the object has each state? (Use linearity of expectation)
- What is the expectation of the sum over all $K$ states of an indicator that at at least one of $N$ time points the object has each state?
- What is the expectation of the number of states the object has over $N$ time points?